# How to call cursor.execute if the connection "with" and "cur" are in another different py file?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

Having **self.con = sqlite3.connect (db)** and **self.cur = self.con.cursor()** in the db.py file, how can I call them in the main.py file to use cursor.execute? I wrote db.self.cur.execute('SELECT Name FROM TableExample'), but obviously I was wrong, there is an error of course

P.S: In db.py do I have to insert the path of the database inside db of the sqlite3.connect(db)?

I had tried like this:

DB.PY

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        sql = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees(
            ID Integer Primary Key,
            example1 integer,
            example2 integer
        )
        """
        self.cur.execute(sql)
        self.con.commit()
```

MAIN.PY

```
from db import Database

db = Database('/home/xxxx/database.db')

def example():
    db.self.cur.execute('SELECT Name FROM TableExample') #error
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result
```

UPDATE: New example in main.py

```
def example():
    db.cur.execute('SELECT Name FROM TableExample')
    result=[row[0] for row in db.cur]
    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems to fix here. The error on this line:

```
db.self.cur.execute('SELECT Name FROM TableExample') #error
```

is because of the use of `self`. You'll want to read up on how to use classes, but in short `self` (named that by convention, not requirement) is how an object instance refers to itself, such as where you set `self.cur` in `__init__()`. You don't refer to `self` outside the object.

Instead, you want to refer to the `cur` attribute of the `db` object like this:

```
db.cur.execute('SELECT Name FROM TableExample')
```

The next issue is the list expression that reads from the database. This:

```
result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
```

is going to cause an error, because `cursor` is not defined. You probably want to refer to the `cur` attribute in the `db` object:

```
result=[row[0] for row in db.cur]
```

However, while this works, it's not the best way to do it. You're implicitly using the results of the last query executed on the cursor, which does work, but is less obvious.

Better would be to create a new cursor object from the query and iterate that:

```
query = db.cur.execute('SELECT Name FROM TableExample')
result = [row[0] for row in query]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. You have been very kind. Now I do some tests with the code you suggested and later or at the latest tomorrow I will let you know (and I will vote your answer of course). Thanks

Comment: As you see in main.py, I call the database db like this: db = Database ('/ home / xxxx / database.db'). The data is entered regularly, because I manually created the table in database.db in the database. All right. But as you said in your answer, the query would not have worked with the automatic table TableExamplee. How can I fix the problem and make the query work with TableExample? (if I don't want to manually create the table inside, but have it automatically created inside database.db '? Thanks

Comment: @heovan1999: Sorry, I said that because your `__init__()` creates a table called `employees` so I assumed that was all that was in the database. My apologies for the confusion. If your `database.db` has the correct table, your query should work fine. (I edited the answer to remove the part about the table name)

Comment: Ah ok, don't worry. Thanks. You are very nice. But what if I wanted to make CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees work, without manually adding the table? (in DB Browser for SQLite). What should I change in CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees to make it create and work properly? Thanks

Comment: It might be best to open another question if you need help with that. Questions are preferably confined to one topic so they're easy to search.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I'm new. So referring to my question, should I delete sql = "" "and its contents? (Considering that I don't need it anymore). db.py file) Thanks

Comment: @heovan1999: Yes, I imagine that should work for you. Remove `sql = .....` and what follows, so that `__init__()` only connects to the DB and creates the cursor. Then you can use `db.cur` and `db.con` to update and commit in `main.py`.

Comment: Maybe due to communication problems (I use Google Translate), I didn't understand what you said about db.cur, db.con and commit in main.py. I have updated my question and below I have inserted an example of the code I currently use (always regarding the question). Is it okay how do I proceed or is there something missing in the code? Thanks

Comment: @heovan1999: I think what you have written should work fine, but as I said, if you need additional help with that, it's best to open a new question.

Comment: You're right. If I need more help, I'll open another question. With these last comments I just wanted to make sure my question is closed and solved, but more importantly that I understand what you suggested to me (I'm new to Python). Thanks

Comment: I have set the question as "solved". I cannot rate your question. Being new here, I don't have enough reputation. I receive this "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: Votate you. Correct, good